# Parallel downloads using simplexml_load_file in PHP

Tags: php, download, simplexml

I want to use PHP to **simultaneously download** data from 2 URLs via `simplexml_load_file` but the script must wait until all data is gathered before going ahead processing the rest of the code.

```
$url1 = "http://www.example.com/api1";
$request1 = simplexml_load_file($url1);

$url2 = 'http://www.example.com/api2';
$request2 = simplexml_load_file("compress.zlib://$url2", NULL, TRUE);

echo 'finished';
```

I want all data is completely downloaded before printing the word *finished*.

How would you edit the script above to accomplish that?

Comment: Id use curl_multi, then simplexml_load_string, simplexml_load_file is not synchronous

Answer (score 1):

Fetching URLs directly while opening "files" with functions such as `simplexml_load_file` is intended as a short-cut for simple cases where you *don't* need things like non-blocking / asynchronous I/O.

Your script as written *will* wait for everything to download before printing the word "finished", but it will also wait for the response from `http://www.example.com/api1` to finish downloading before starting the request to `http://www.example.com/api2`.

You will need to break your problem down:

- Download the contents of two URLs, in parallel (or more accurately "asynchronously"). Your result will be two strings.
- Parse each of those strings using `simplexml_load_string`.

The most popular HTTP library for PHP is [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), but you should be able to find many alternatives, and guides to writing your own using the [built-in cURL functions](http://php.net/curl) if you search for terms like "PHP asynchronous HTTP" or "PHP parallel HTTP requests".